# The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` is a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to connect my api to Digital Ocean to prepare for deployment and when trying to connect to the database I get the following error "UError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string." My server still connects to Digital Ocean as well. the api has worked perfect while in development as well.

Below is the db.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () => {
  const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.underline.bold);
};

module.exports = connectDB;
```

And below is the server.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const colors = require('colors');
const fileupload = require('express-fileupload');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const helmet = require('helmet');
var xss = require('xss-clean');
var rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
var hpp = require('hpp');
var cors = require('cors');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const errorHandler = require('./middleware/error');
// Load env files
dotenv.config({ path: './config.config.env' });

// Connect to Database
connectDB();

// Route files
const bootcamps = require('./routes/bootcamps');
const courses = require('./routes/courses');
const auth = require('./routes/auth');
const users = require('./routes/users');
const reviews = require('./routes/reviews');
const app = express();

// Body Parser
app.use(express.json());

// Cookie parser
app.use(cookieParser());

// Dev logging middleware
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

// File uploading
app.use(fileupload());

// Sanitize data
app.use(mongoSanitize());

// Set security headers
app.use(helmet());

// Prevent XSS attacks
app.use(xss());

// Rate Limiting
const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000, // 10 minutes
  max: 100,
});

app.use(limiter);

// Prevent http param pollution
app.use(hpp());

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors());

// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Mount Routers
app.use('/api/v1/bootcamps', bootcamps);
app.use('/api/v1/courses', courses);
app.use('/api/v1/auth', auth);
app.use('/api/v1/users', users);
app.use('/api/v1/reviews', reviews);

app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  )
);

// Handle unhandled promise rejections
process.on('unhandledRejection', (err, promise) => {
  console.log(`UError: ${err.message}`.red);

  // Close server and exit process
  server.close(() => process.exit(1));
});
```

I would appreciate any help than you.

Comment: Check your process environment variable `MONGO_URI` value. Is it windows or linux in which u are running this code?

Comment: Thank you  the MONGO_URI variable is the same it has been all through the project and it's been working. I'm operating on windows 10